# eth0 disappears with "Graceful transmit stop did not complete". PHY gone?

Tags: network-interface, embedded, ethernet, ifconfig

An i.MX6dl-based embedded device with NXP kernel 4.14.98 receives data packages over `eth0`. In one of some hundred cases the interface stops after twenty minutes or an hour with no obvious reason. The system log says

```
[ 1450.764118] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Graceful transmit stop did not complete!
[ 1450.771484] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
```

No suspend or powerdown was issued. Nor is there some known event different from the cases where the interface stays up. In this state, `ifconfig` reports

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:D6:25:76:A2
      inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::230:d6ff:fe25:76a2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6844776 errors:5 dropped:0 overruns:4 frame:1
      TX packets:33 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:441617696 (421.1 MiB)  TX bytes:5570 (5.4 KiB)
```

The overruns are unusual. When I try to restart:

```
# ifconfig eth0 down
# ifconfig eth0 up
  ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Connection timed out
```

while the `dmesg` report `fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: could not attach to PHY`. The PHY is a Micrel KSZ9031.

Could a blocking PHY generate the `Graceful transmit stop did not complete` message?

What could try to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: Sorry if this appears as a rant, but embedded systems are always lagging in kernel version. even for 4.14.x there's 4.14.235. The standard method when an hardware bug happens, would be to update the kernel to the last version (or even just revision) and see if it was already fixed, then do more research.

Comment: Certainly no rant, but a fair remark. Unfortunally weeks of work to adapt a new kernel version to our yocto. But I can have a look at the changelog of the PHY driver. So thank you for the hint.

Comment: I posted this question to U&L because I thought that you could name some OS tools to further debug the problem (and I feel at home here). If you think this problem fits better in a different corner of SE, please tell me so.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a undocumented bug in the PMIC (Dialog Semiconductors) that powered the Micrel KSZ9031. The auto mode of the buck regulator was not reliable and could get into a fail state. Choosing "fixed PWM" mode solved the issue.

So in the end, this was not a U&L related cause, but I leave it here because someone may stumble over it searching for a similar problem.